# how to prevent the submenu from flowing out of screen, making it to appear more left when the window size is too narrow?

Tags: css

I'm trying to prevent the submenu from creating a horizontal scrollbar and so flowing out of screen when the window/screen size get too small.

[imgage to clarify the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqarp.jpg)

I dont know how long the tags (words) in the menu will be yet.
I tried to make the width of the sub menu based on its content (lenght of words) but that caused unsolveable (at least for me) problems positioning the subsub menu dynamically based on the varible width of the sub menu.

Here is also a [link to a pen](https://codepen.io/undefined999/pen/WMjWba)

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

  // add JS-classes into the HTML-Tag
  $('html').addClass('js');

  // add classes for sub menus and sub menus toggle button
  $(".site-nav li > ul").parent('li').addClass('has-sub-menu');
  $(".site-nav li > ul").addClass('sub-menu');

  // create button for expand- und collapse the menu and render it into the header
  var create_toggle_nav_button = ['<div class="toggle-site-nav">Menu</div>'].join("");
  $("header").append(create_toggle_nav_button); 

  // create button for expand- und collapse the sub menu  for mobile view and add them to all sub menus
  var create_sub_toggle_button = ['<span class="toggle-sub-menu"></span>'].join("");
  $(".has-sub-menu > a").after(create_sub_toggle_button);

  // define variables
  var $menu = $('.site-nav'),
  $toggle_nav = $('.toggle-site-nav'),
  $toggle_sub_menu = $('.toggle-sub-menu');

  // collapse and expand function of the main menu
  $toggle_nav.click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $menu.slideToggle();
  });

  // collapse and expand function of the drop down menu for mobile view
  $toggle_sub_menu.click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').slideToggle();
  });

  // display hidden elements again, when browserwindow is resized by user
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 900) {
     $('.site-nav').removeAttr('style');
     $('.sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
    });

    // collapse navigation automatically to the left, when it run out of the viewport
  $(".site-nav .has-sub-menu").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {

         var nav_element = $('ul:first', this);
         var element_offset = nav_element .offset();
         var element_offset_left = element_offset.left;
         var element_width = nav_element.width();
         var viewport_width = $(window).width();

         var element_in_viewport = (element_offset_left + element_width <= viewport_width);
                  
         if ( ! element_in_viewport ) {
             $(this).addClass('sub-left');
         } else {
             $(this).removeClass('sub-left');
         }
     });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body::after {
 content:'';
 position: fixed;
 bottom:1em;
 right:1em;
 opacity: 0.5;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 z-index: 9999;
}

header {
 width:100%;
 background: white;
}

.container {
 max-width:1000px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }

.logo {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 padding:1em;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:gray; /* ? */
}

.site-nav {
 z-index: 9999;
}

.site-nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
}

.site-nav >ul> li {
 display: inline-block;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:auto;
  padding:0;
}

.site-nav a {
 display:inline-flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding:1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
 text-decoration:none;
  height:100%;
 width:100%;
 color:white;     /* text color of all */
 background:#5a595a; /* background color main nav Link 1 */
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 z-index: 9999;
}

.site-nav a:hover {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 */
}

.js .site-nav {
 display:none;
}

.js .sub-menu {
 display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.js .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  top:0px;
  right:100%;
  left:auto;
  text-align:right;
}

  .js .has-sub-menu { 
  position:relative;
  top:100%;
  left:0px;
}

.sub-menu li:last-of-type {
 padding-bottom:0;
}

.sub-menu a {
 background:#676567; /* background color menu 2.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a {
 background:#747274; /* background color menu 2.1.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 */
}

/* toggles */

.toggle-site-nav {
 background:#5a595a; /* background color of menu button when resized */
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 padding:1em;
 color:white; /* text color of the word menu in menu button when resized */
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index: 9999;
}

.toggle-site-nav:hover {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* mouseover color of menu button when resized */
}

.toggle-sub-menu {
 display:none;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu {
 display:flex;
  position:absolute;
  align-content: center;
  right:0em;
  top:1.05em; /* hight of the borders */
 background:#817e81; /* backgound of annoying squares when resized */
 height: 15px;
 width: 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu.active {
 background: #DCDCDC; /* color of annoying square after clicking on it when resized */
}
 
.toggle-sub-menu:hover,
.toggle-sub-menu.active:hover  {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* mouseover of annoying squares when resized */
}


@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
 
 .logo {
  width:auto;
  float:left; 
 }
 
 .site-nav {
  width:auto;
  display: flex !important;
 }

 .site-nav a {
  border:none;
 }
 
 .site-nav li {
  width:auto;
  padding:0;
 }

 .site-nav li:hover {
  background:rgba(52,50,52,1); /* mouseover background color of all menu */
 }

 .has-sub-menu a {
  padding-right: 2em; /* check this value */
 }

 .has-sub-menu:after { /* check this for editing the stripes */
  display:flex;
    content:'';
  position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
  top:1.2em;
  right: 0;
  width:1em;
  height:30%;
  background:#817e81; /* color of stripes in main menu when it has submenu */
 }

 /* sub menu */
 .site-nav li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; /* width of sub menus */
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: -25px;
 }

 .sub-menu {display:none;}
 
 .sub-menu li {
  width:100%; 
 }
 
 .sub-menu > a {
  width:100%;
  display:block; 
 }

 .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:after {
  background:#817e81; /* color of stripes of Link 2.1 menu when it has submenu */
 }
 
 .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:hover .sub-menu {
  display:block; 
  position:absolute;
    width: 300px; /* width of subsub menues */
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: 224px;
    top: 0px;
 }
 
 .toggle-site-nav,
 .toggle-sub-menu {
  display:none !important; 
 }

 /* navigations items, which collapse to the left */

 .sub-left > .sub-menu {
  left:auto;
  right:0;
 }

 .site-nav .sub-menu .sub-left > .sub-menu {
  left:-275px;
 }
}

@media (max-width :899px){
  .site-nav {
    z-index: 999999999999999999;
    margin-top: 19px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">loooooong</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">loooooooooooooooooong</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">loooooooong</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```